# Style Triggers being recursivly applied

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Style Trigger to expand an image when the mouse is over it (actually a border around the image) and contract when it moves off. This is done via an animated scale transform.

However if the mouse moves off the expanding image but is still within the area it is expanding into, before the mouse over animation has completed, the expand and contract animations get constantly triggered causing the image to flicker between expanding and contracting.

```
 <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ScaleTransform/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="2.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="1" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.5" AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.4"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="1" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.5" AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.4"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>

        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="1.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="1.2" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.4"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" From="1.2" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.4"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BorderColourConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    BorderThickness="1.5" Style="{StaticResource ThumbnailScale}">
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
    </Border.Background>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="{Binding ThumbnailWidth, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Height="{Binding ThumbnailHeight, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</Border>
```

Is there some way to stop the recursive triggering of the animations and so stop the continual change in the image size?

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting the question I looked at a slow motion video of what was happening and figured out what was happening and how to fix it.

The problem was with the second (and subsequent) invocation of the animation's start point.

They assumed that the previous animation had finished when it hadn't. So by removing the "From" clause in the animations they started from their current scaling and this solved the problem.